# How to normalize a list such that it works for all cases

Tags: python, list

Task: Given this code:

```
def normalize(lst):
    s = sum(lst)
    return list(map(lambda v: v / s, lst))
```

This code works for:

```
normalize([1, 2, 5, 4])
```

But not for this (due to division of zero):

```
normalize([1, 2, -7, 4])
```

Without modifying the normalize function, implement this strategy in the safe_normalize function such that:

```
safe_normalize([1, 2, -5, 2])
```

gives

```
[1, 2, -5, 2]
```

I tried this but it fails:

```
def safe_normalize(lst):
    def normalize(lst):
        s = sum(lst)
        if s == o:
            return s
        elif s!= 0:
            new_s = s
            return list(map(lambda v: v / new_s, lst))
    return normalize(lst)
```

Comment: It seems that there's a typo: "if s == o:" "o" instead of "0"

Comment: You also have `return s`, where `s` is the sum of the list instead of a normalized list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't modify normalize but you assume it is given you can just wrap call to it in try except block and return input list if ZeroDivisioneError occurs.

```
def safe_normalize(lst):
    try:
        return normalize(lst)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return lst
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the good old `or`-idiom:

```
def safe_normalize(lst):
    s = sum(lst) or 1
    return list(v/s for v in lst)
```

Off-topic, but note how are generator-expressions more readable. List comprehension is even better:

```
 [v/s for v in lst]
```

Comment: Or use a list comprehension: `[v/s for v in lst]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a flag to enforce safeness and catch the exception.

Also, in python 2.7 you will get integer division. If you don't want this then add a float conversion. Also, in 2.7 the call to `list()` is extraneous as `map()` returns a list anyway. You might want to add the list call in the client code.

```
def normalize(lst, safe=False):
    s = sum(lst);
    try:
        return map(lambda v: float(v)/s, lst)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        if safe:
            return lst
        else:
            raise


print(normalize([1,2,3,4]))
print(normalize([1,2,3,-6], safe=True))
print(list(normalize([1,2,3,-6], safe=True)))
for item in normalize([1,2,3,-6], safe=True):
    print(item)
```

Comment: If it's Python3, `map` will return generator and division is float by default.

Comment: I guess my comments are for the 2.7 dinosaurs then.